# aligning child divs to parent div's baseline

Tags: html, css

This is a very simple css question.

I have posted my codes here. 
http://jsbin.com/furafi/1/edit

How do I align all the child divs to the parent div's baseline?
Now it's aligned to the "topline".

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
float: left;
```

to

```
display: inline-block;
```

`float` treats them as if they're all inline, but `inline-block` gives the best of both worlds. Additionally, remove the `vertical-align` line. It's probably [the most misused property in CSS](http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/).

To fix the spacing between the boxes, make sure there isn't any whitespace between the `div`s in the markup itself.

Comment: Thanks. but what about if I add a float: right to one of the division?

The thing is I need one of the division floating on the other side. it immediately breaks the display flow I think.

http://jsbin.com/yekezura/1/edit

Comment: @user3740222: In that case, you're best off with [absolute positioning](http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/). It seems that you will have to another follow-up question, since that's not in your question statement.

Comment: Thanks, I tried your way. 
Is it the most logical way of doing it?
http://jsbin.com/bekezuwe/1/edit

Actually I find this is not really a flexible solution as I have to self-define the values for the "top" attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Try this css:

```
.valign.bottom { 
    vertical-align: bottom;
}


.block { padding: 20px; display: inline-block}

.block.red {background: red; width:50px;}

.block.yellow {background: yellow;  width:50px;}

.block.green {background: green;  width:100px;}
```

The issue was `float: left` that breaks display flow

Comment: Thanks. but what about if I add a float: right to one of the division?

The thing is I need one of the division floating on the other side. it immediately breaks the display flow I think.

http://jsbin.com/yekezura/1/edit

Comment: then you can use `position:absolute; bottom: 0` to set all divs positioned to bottom or do wrapping divs to handle the correct behaviour

Answer (score 1):

I have found that `display: table` and `display:table-cell` are the best way to go when vertical aligning divs. I have an [example plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/wv2Ry67GTRoFyVlNUQzn?p=preview)

**HTML**

```
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="myTable">
      <div class="myCell">
        <div class="bblock red">my bottom aligned div 1</div>
        <div class="bblock yellow">my bottom aligned div 2</div>
        <div class="bblock green">my bottom aligned div 3</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div class="myTable">
      <div class="myCell">
        <div class="mblock red">my middle aligned div 1</div>
        <div class="mblock yellow">my middle aligned div 2</div>
        <div class="mblock green">my middle aligned div 3</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div class="myTable">
      <div class="myCell">
        <div class="tblock red">my top aligned div 1</div>
        <div class="tblock yellow">my top aligned div 2</div>
        <div class="tblock green">my top aligned div 3</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
.myTable { 
  display:table;
  background-color:blue;
}

.myCell { 
  display:table-cell; 
}

.bblock {
  padding:20px;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom; 
}

.mblock {
  padding:20px;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle; 
}

.tblock {
  padding:20px;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align: top; 
}

.red { 
  background-color: red; 
  width:50px;
}

.yellow {
   background-color: yellow;  
}

.green {
  background-color: green;  
  width:100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display: flex;` in you parent div to get what you wanted. Look for documentation here: [CSS display Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp).

Be careful as it is only supported in CSS3.